# gdal_merge.py in Conda says DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, gdal, conda

I ran across this issue about a year ago, solved it, and subsequently lost my notes.  I'm running `gdal_merge.py` through the command line in a Conda environment.

```
>%CONDA_PREFIX%\Scripts\gdal_merge.py -o output.tif input1.tif input2.tif
```

I know the location of `gdal_merge.py` works, because I run other scripts there (`gdal_calc.py`) and the script is there.  So it's not a `path/to/python_merge.py` issue.
The more important clue is the Traceback:

```
(gdal_env)%CONDA_PREFIX%\Scripts\gdal_merge.py -o output.tif input1.tif input2.tif
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\envs\gdal_env\Scripts\gdal_merge.py", line 4, in   
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('GDAL==3.6.2', 'gdal_merge.py')  
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3251, in   
    @_call_aside  
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside  
    f(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set  
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()  
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master  
    ws.require(__requires__)  
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require  
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))  
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve  
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)  
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'GDAL==3.6.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

It appears that for `gdal_merge.py`, it's looking in my ArcGIS Python Distribution(?). Also confusing, is that `gdalinfo --version` yields the correct distribution - 3.6.2.

Comment: Thanks @user2856 - did not know the `{}` indent formatter.  I found some posting tips and was able to format it a little better.  I'll delete these comments in 10 minutes or so, save for my second comment.

Comment: @user2856 I got it!  I forget to do add the `python` before the entire command line call.  Pretty silly.  `python %CONDA_PREFIX%\Scripts\gdal_merge.py -o output.tif input1.tif input2.tif`.  Mission accomplished.  I'll go ahead and delete the question soon, as it's likely only to confuse people.  Thanks.